# passing struct pointer causes integer overflow for seemingly no reason

Tags: c

Note: I solved it myself in the process of writing this question. It's amazing how just writing out a problem, and including the details, can often help one solve their own problem. Not to mention reading the output of `-Wall` helped a bunch.

Nevertheless, I'm still posting this so that people having this problem in the future can solve it themselves.

If you think I should community wiki this, let me know.

---

The original question:

For some reason, when I pass a struct pointer through two functions, it seems to warp the data inside.

I'm at my wit's end with this. Maybe this is an ambitious project for a C noob like me, but nontheless, I can't seem to figure out why this is happening.

Here are some relevant code snippets:

from data.h:

```
typedef struct data{
  unsigned int dollar_bank : 32;
  unsigned int dollar_bank_extra : 32;
  // 13 more ints
} data;

void file_save(data *d, char *file);
```

data.c:

```
void file_save(data *d, char *file){
  FILE *f = fopen(file,"w");
  fprintf(f,
    "%05i,%05i,[...]%05i",
    d->dollar_bank,
    d->dollar_bank_extra,
    // etc
  );
  fclose(f);
}
```

main.c:

```
render(&d);
prompt(&d);
data_save(&d,"data"); // Saves correctly
```

interface.c:

```
static void exec_command(data *d, char *cmd, int *exit_code){
  // Here I have this debug line,
  printf("%i\n",d->dollar_bank); 
  // supposed to print 1000 (as it does in main())
  // but prints a random number like -1246981692364 instead
  // if I invoke file_save() here, it writes garbage into the file.  Not very useful.
}
void prompt(data *d){
  char cmd[5];
  int exit_code = 0;
  while(1){
    // ...
    exec_command(&d, cmd, &exit_code);
    if(exit_code)    break;
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate any help that could possibly be given with this. I feel like I'm missing something painfully obvious. If you need more code snippets, just ask.

Compiler = GCC 4.7.3

Compiler Output:

```
interface.c: In function ‘exec_command’:
interface.c:102:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘file_save’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
In file included from interface.c:3:0:
data.h:22:6: note: expected ‘struct data *’ but argument is of type ‘struct data **’
interface.c: In function ‘prompt’:
interface.c:123:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exec_command’ from incompatible  pointer type [enabled by default]
interface.c:93:6: note: expected ‘struct data *’ but argument is of type ‘struct data **’
interface.c:121:10: warning: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something painfully obvious.

Comment: For me, this is perfectly OK. Answering your own questions is encouraged behavior, and you are obviously posting this on good faith :-) the only thing I'd think of is that, in a couple of days, you accept your own answer so that the question doesn't stay open (no accepted answer).

Comment: @Streppel thanks for letting me know! And I'll make sure to do that. as soon as Stack overflow lets me. Though if a better answer with more detail comes along, I'll be sure to accept that one instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution came to me when I was copying the output of GCC (with `-Wall`, of course).

```
interface.c:123:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘exec_command’ from incompatible  pointer type [enabled by default]
interface.c:93:6: note: expected ‘struct data *’ but argument is of type ‘struct data **’
```

I thought about it, and realized that I *was* missing something painfully obvious: passing `&d` (the address of the original struct) to another function, would be pointing an address of an address. Not even a valid pointer as far as I know, but it still got interpreted as `struct data **`. This means that with the saving function, I was passing `struct data ***`.

The solution was as simple as changing:

```
exec_command(&d,[...]);
```

to

```
exec_command(d,[...]);
```

So now instead of printing `-12345474293845`, it prints `1000`. Hooray!

---

Again, if you think I should community wiki this question/answer, let me know. Then people can add their knowledge onto the subject of pointers-to-pointers.

Alternatively, if you think I should delete this question/answer, let me know. I don't want to step on anyone's toes.

Comment: also, I _am_ pretty curious about just what is going on when you pass an "address of an address". Where is it getting the number? Why doesn't it crash? Why doesn't the compiler throw a full-blown error?